# Why was my question closed on the grounds of "not a real question"?

Tags: discussion

https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/112389/the-pyro-the-gender-ambiguity-problem?noredirect=1#comment150637_112389

In this question, I clearly asked for facts (game files, references) that pointed out the nuances of the Pyro's gender.  I don't see how this was closed for "not a real question".

An answer could have gone along the lines of:

```
The main menu refers to the Pyro as either "him" or "her", randomly changing each time the game is started.
The game files (scripts/global_actors.txt) refers to the pyro as "male"
The Pyro's Mildly Disturbing Halloween Mask shows a picture of a small bird, implying that the pyro is a chick
```

Answer (score 9):

Like I said in my [recent](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/112389/the-pyro-the-gender-ambiguity-problem#comment150637_112389) [comments](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/112389/the-pyro-the-gender-ambiguity-problem#comment150643_112389):

> This really isn't a question, but a discussion. It belongs on a forum, not a Q&A site
>
> You're asking for arguments supporting an unknown fact, aka an opinion. It's essentially a literary analysis of the Team Fortress 2 lore, which isn't the kind of question we allow here. It just doesn't work.

Since there is no definite answer on this from valve that's all this is, literary analysis and speculation.   We're not a forum, nor are we an English class. Literary analysis of this kind doesn't work on Arqade.

Answer (score 3):

Subjective questions that don't concern facts are closed as Not Constructive.  Your question was closed as Not A Real Question.

> It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or **rhetorical** and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form.

Comment: This doesn't answer what I'm asking. I'm asking why, not asking for something I see when I click on my question.

Comment: Your question is rhetorical.  Simple as that.

Comment: How so? Explain?

Comment: @Retrosaur [In simple terms, it is a question asked more to produce an effect than to summon an answer.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhetorical_question)